# Install Ubuntu with HDMI cable

Tags: grub2, laptop, hdmi

One of my friends wants to start using Ubuntu, but he has the following problem:
The screen of his laptop is broken, and he has connected his laptop to an HDMI TV in order to see. I wanna know if Ubuntu setup would appear in the screen and if it wouldn't what he should do to get it working. The version of Ubuntu he is going to install is Ubuntu 14.04, but he wants to dual boot it with Windows 7. The laptop is an HP620.
I also want to the GRUB screen appear in the HDMI, if possible.

Comment: That depends on the graphics adapter BIOS. My friends' netbook mirrors everything from the (broken) internal display to the VGA connector until a proper graphics driver takes control, but I've seen different behaviour on other systems.

Comment: @DavidFoerster his HP has an old school GM45 chipset, itll load on demand.

Answer (score 2):

Your HP620 has an old GM45 Graphic Chipset, this chipset work as an on demand process.  Meaning once you plug it into the HDMI port you automatically see it, since Ubuntu works kinda the same way.  The bios will also load on screen as well, making it a nice thing to have.

Comment: @Haris: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)